# Как можно из vector<int> удалить элементы которые содержатся во втором векторе?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

У нас есть вектор `vector<int> first`, еще есть второй вектор `vector<int> second`.

Нужно из первого вектора удалить все элементы, которые входят во второй. Понимаю,что можно решить в лоб 2-мя циклами, но если есть какие-то идеи,то прошу помочь.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Можно с помощью [std::remove_if](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) + [std::vector::erase](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), но скорость будет такая же. Изменится только размер исходного кода.

Comment: Можно предварительно отсортировать второй вектор и искать в нем элементы через `std::binary_search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если векторы неупорядочены, то только "в лоб", т.е. вашими "двумя циклами". Если разрешается использование дополнительной памяти, то имеет смысл предварительно занести второй вектор в какой-то эффективное представление множества (`std::set`, `std::unordered_set`).

Если упорядочен только второй вектор, то проверка наличия элемента в нем может выполняться эффективно через бинарный поиск (`std::binary_search`)

Если оба вектора упорядочены, то задача решается намного эффективнее через синхронизированный проход по векторами (алгоритмы типа `std::set_difference`).